# Probability distribution for random walk samples of Voronoi decomposition of high-dimensional space of exponentially-distributed points

Tags: probability, distributions

I've got a protein I'm modeling. One thing I do with it is randomly perturb the protein for a fixed amount of time at a chosen temperature, and then minimize it so that its configuration reaches a local energy minimum. Higher temperatures can reach energy minima further and further away from the starting configuration. I repeat this hundreds of thousands of times at different temperatures.

I've noticed that energy minima are sparse enough that at lower temperatures, I'll get repeats of the same minimum. In fact, at the lowest temperature I sample at ($kT = 1\,\text{REU}$), less than 1% of samples are unique. The portion of uniques as a function of temperature looks vaguely like the CDF of a gamma distribution (not to say that that's what it actually is).

How can one use the temperature vs. portion of uniques data to model the distribution of energy minima as a function of configuration-space distance from the starting point (which, by the way, is the global minimum)? I've gotten to the end of the analysis, but I have no background in statistics and would appreciate it if someone with more stats knowledge than me went over it.

- The minima space is a 1000+-dimensional space, with each minimum as a point in the space. The density of minima decreases exponentially as you get further away from the origin; we can model this with the function
  $$N(r) = N_{0}(1-e^{-\alpha r})$$
  representing the number of minima within a distance of $r$ from the origin, for some $\alpha$. (This is perhaps the most weakly-motivated approximation here. In fact, it can't possibly be true, not only because there is certifiably just 1 minimum at the center, but also because the data has an inflection point, meaning that the mode of the minima density is probably somewhere past $r=0$. But I'm at a loss as to what else it could be.)
- The random perturbation search is a random walk in the minima space, with the number of steps in the random walk linearly increasing with temperature. This means that the probability of the random walk ending up at any particular distance from the origin is approximately
  $$P(r; T) = \frac{2r}{\beta T}e^{-r^{2}/\beta T}$$
  for some $\beta$.
- Wherever the random walk ends up, the minimization will then carry it to the nearest minimum. This is equivalent to a random walk on a nearest-neighbor partition (aka Voronoi decomposition) of the minima space, and then taking a sample of whichever partition you end up in. At a given $r$ for a finite number of samples, this will look like multinomial sampling with probabilities proportional to the hypervolumes of the cross-sections of the partitions that intersect the hypershell of that $r$. And because we're assuming that the minima are evenly distributed within such a hypershell, the probability of getting any particular minimum is the same, i.e. $\left(\frac{dN(r)}{dr}\right)^{-1}$. And this means that, for $n$ samples at a temperature $T$, our expected number of unique minima hit should be
  $$ M(n, T) = \int_0^\infty \frac{dN(r)}{dr}\left(1-\left(1-\left(\frac{dN(r)}{dr}\right)^{-1}\right)^{n}\right)P(r;T)\,dr $$
  where $N(r)$ and $P(r;T)$ are the functions defined above. Mathematica couldn't do the integral, unfortunately, so I guess it's something really weird.